# JPA Container filter one to many relationship

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, jpacontainer

I have a Vaadin8 application and the following two classes.
(Classes simplified for readability)

**Car Class:**

```java
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "carId")
    private Collection<CarLeasingDuration> carLeasingDurationCollection;
}
```

**Car Leasing Duration Class:**

```java
public class CarLeasingDuration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_datetime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDatetime;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "end_datetime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDatetime;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cost")
    private float cost;
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Car carId;
}
```

You have a car that can be leased multiple times, for a duration of time (startDatetime to endDatetime).

I want to create a ComboBox, with a list of all cars, except the ones that their leasing duration has expired. So I create a JPA Container from the Car class

```java
EntityManager em = JPAContainerFactory.createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit(HelpConstants.PERSISTENT_UNIT);
JPAContainer<Car> carContainer = JPAContainerFactory.makeReadOnly(Car.class, em);
```

I've tried something like this, which of course doesn't work

```java
carContainer.addNestedContainerProperty("carLeasingDurationCollection.carLeasingDuration.endDatetime");
carContainer.addContainerFilter(new Not(new Compare.Greater("carLeasingDurationCollection.carLeasingDuration.endDatetime", new Date())));
```

I'm getting error for invalid property name.

Is there a way to filter this container based on the One to Many relationship that there is between Car and CarLeasingDuration? And if not, how would I go about doing that?

Thank you.